# Why won't divs occupy specified space?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div with a width of 900px. In that I have two divs with widths of 400px and 500px. I can't figure out why these divs won't occupy at least the 900px of the wrapper.

```
   .wrapper{
   background:blue;
   width:900px;
   height:250px;
   }

   .div1{
   background:yellow;
   height:250px;
   width:400px;
   float:left;
   }

   .div2{
   background:orange;
   height:250px;
   width: 500px;
   }

   .div2 li {
   display: list-item;
   list-style-type: none;
   }


   <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="div1"><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-gMmeweshbOo/Up307AA-         1hI/AAAAAAAAAGE/cU_E9cGjWks/w400-h300-no/google_trans.png"></div>
   <div class="div2">
   <h2>Important Documents<h2>

   <ul>
   <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link1</a></li>

   <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link2</a></li>

   <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link3</a></li>

   <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link4</a></li>

   <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link5</a></li>
   </ul>


   </div>
   </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swbpC

Comment: You don't need `display: list-item;` on `.div2 li`, `li` is already `list-item`.

Comment: That's what I thought but this was the only way I could take away the bullets. Is there another way?

Comment: `list-style-type:none;` takes the bullet points, not `display:list-item`.

Comment: `.div2 ul { list-style: none; }`

Comment: I am with the answers from Henk and Volvox. Consider checking this page to understand how it works: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: @Martin http://www.w3fools.com/ user2189: Better have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  .div2
   {
      background:orange;
      height:250px;
      width: 500px;
      float:left;
   }
```

add `float:left` to the div2 as well

Answer (score 1):

```
.div2{
background:orange;
height:250px;
width: 500px;
float:left; //HERE!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `overflow:auto;` to `.div2` so that its content does not overflow the container.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code, both divs had the correct width as-is. However, the div2 element was being pushed underneath the div1 element. div2 is lacking the float:right property. I believe this is what you are attempting to do.